# Google Map , Cache problem

Tags: php, google-maps, caching

i am using Google Maps to draw some polylines with markers. Everything is working fine. I am facing problem with Cache. Whenever i do a change and see the Graph it does not reflect the change first time, I have to refresh the page 2 times to see the new change.

To avoid this i am using this at the top of the page :

```
<?PHP
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
header("Expires: Sat, 28 Jul 2007 05:00:00 GMT");
?>
```

However it is not working as i have refresh the page almost 2 times.

Can anyone suggest me any alternative way to do the same.

Thanks
-Zack

Answer (score 0):

How about sticking this at the top of your script? It'll change the URL of the script each time you access the script. This should prevent browser caching...

```
if (!isset($_GET['time'])) {

    // url of current page, with an added timestamp
    $host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $url = "http://$host$page?time=".time();

    // redirect back to this same page, but changing the URL 
    // to include the current unix timestamp
    header('Location: '.$url);
    exit;
}
```